# Spring framework e mail confirmation link error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have already created an e mail confirmation in spring boot it is working nicely, and also I created a link when a user click it should say "confirmed"but I did not figure it out how to do that?

E mail sender java class:

```
 @Component
    public class EmailSender {

        @Autowired 
        JavaMailSender javaEmailSender;
        public void sendEmail(String to, String subject, String text) throws MessagingException {
             MimeMessage message = javaEmailSender.createMimeMessage();
             MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message,
                        MimeMessageHelper.MULTIPART_MODE_MIXED_RELATED,
                        StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
            helper.setTo(to);
            helper.setSubject(subject);
            helper.setText(text, true);
            helper.addInline("logo.jpg", new ClassPathResource("./images/logo.jpg"));
            javaEmailSender.send(message);
        }

}


 E mail template Loader:



     @Component
        public class EmailTemplateLoader {

            @Autowired
            private Configuration freemakerConfiguration;

            public String getEmailBody(String name, String confirmationLink) throws TemplateException {

                try {
                    Template template = freemakerConfiguration.getTemplate("EmailConfirmation.ftl");

                    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    data.put("name", name);
                    data.put("confirmationLink", confirmationLink);

                    return FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString(template, data);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (TemplateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return "";
            }
        }
```

My signup Resource :

```
@Autowired
    private SignupService signupService;
    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

    @RequestMapping(value = "user/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> signup(@RequestBody UserType user) throws SignUpException {
        URL requestUrl = null;
        try {
            requestUrl = new URL(httpServletRequest.getRequestURL().toString());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            logger.debug("Malformed Request Url");
        }
        logger.debug(requestUrl.toString());
        signupService.signUp(user, requestUrl.getHost());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "user/confirmation", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> confirmSignUp(@RequestParam("u") String loginName, @RequestParam("p") String token) {
        try {
            signupService.emailConfirmation(loginName, token);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (SignUpException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
```

So, As I told I can send an email successfully, but I could not sort how I can write confirmation successfully

Answer (score 0):

do you want to send confirmation mail or just want to know confirmation status that mail has been sent? Please specify it.

You Can add some code in your SignUpService where you have implemented 
 emailConfiguration() method

@Autowired
private Configuration freemarkerConfiguration;

and add like this in method to get verification

Template t = freemarkerConfiguration.getTemplate("verification.ftl");
String text = FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString(t,object);

or you can do something with ResponseEntity while returning confirmSignup() method You can add some DTO also to get confirmation status.

Comment: I have link on e mail, When I click my own link, lt should  redirect my template which is verification.ftl           well confirmation status basicly

Comment: as i edited my answer you can do something like that in your service code

Comment: Thank you so much for suggestions, can you give me example on the code